# How to retrieve newest row in an Azure Table?

Tags: c#, azure, nosql

I am trying to retrieve the newest row created in the Primary Minute Metrics tables that is automatically created by Azure. Is there any way to do this without scanning through the whole table? The partition key is basically the timestamp in a different format. For example:

```
20150811T1250
```

However, there is no way for me to tell what the latest partitionkey is, so I can't just query by partition. Also, the row key is useless since all the rows have the same rowkey. I am completely stumped on how I would do this even though it seems like a really basic thing to do. Any ideas?

An example of  a few partition keys of rows in the table:

`20150813T0623
20150813T0629
20150813T0632
20150813T0637
20150813T0641
20150813T0646
20150813T0650
20150813T0654`

EDIT: As a followup question. Is there a way to scan the table backwards? That would allow me to just get the first row scanned since that would be the latest row.

Comment: If I get the ask right, you want to get the latest row created in the table •$MetricsMinutePrimaryTransactionsTable

Comment: Yes, that's correct @BrijRajSingh

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to querying data, Azure Tables offer very limited choices. Given that you know how the PartitionKey gets assigned (YYYYMMDDTHHmm format), one possible solution would be to query from current date/time (in UTC) minus some offset to current date/time and go from there.

For example, assuming start time is 03-Dec-2015 00:00:00. What you could do is try to fetch data from 02-Dec-2015 23:00:00 to 03-Dec-2015 00:00:00 and see if any records are returned. If the records are returned, you can simply take the last entry in the resultset and that would be your latest entry. If no records are found, then you move back by 1 hour (i.e. from 02-Dec-2015 22:00:00 to 02-Dec-2015 23:00:00) and fetch records again and repeat this till the time you find matching result.

Yet another idea (though a bit convoluted one) is to create another table and periodically copy the data from the main table to this new table. When you copy the data, what you would need to do is take the `PartitionKey` value, create a Date/Time object out of it, subtract that from `DateTime.MaxValue`. Calculate the ticks for this new value and use that as the `PartitionKey` for your new entity (you would need to convert that ticks into string and do some string prepadding so that all values are of same length). Now the latest entries will always be on the top.

Comment: I actually already attempted this idea before posting the question (the first idea you suggested). However, some accounts don't have recent entries to the table so it would take a very long time to iterate to a partition key that matched. That second idea seems like a bit much IMO.